# Randomly define the training size in train_test_split sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, scikit-learn

I am trying to split data that I have into `40%` training and `60%` validation, then I want to repeat this `30` times, each time with random training and different validation. How can I do this? (not using `Kfold`)

This is what I wrote but I am getting the same results every time for accuracy, I do not know how to do this with different training and validation each time. My accuracy is the same for each iteration, I don't know why.

```
for i in range (30):
      X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(df,y, 
      train_size=0.4, shuffle=True)
      metrics.accuracy_score(linsvc.predict(X_train), R_train)
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by same results, what did you do to check if they were same?

Comment: Yes, I have to repeat this `30` times with different partitions. However, I put training to `.4` and set shuffle to true, I thought this may change training to random, but the training set is still `40%` of data.

Comment: can you try changing random_state argument with a random number that you generate?

Comment: You mean: `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(df,y, 
      train_size=0.4, shuffle=False, random_state=42)` ? Does it change the training size randomly next time?

Comment: Are you doing your model fitting and scoring inside of the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, before the loop I should do one experiment and fit my model. Inside the loop i should repeat the experiment 30 times but this time with random training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve a random training size for each of the 30 iterations you can use a random generator and then use this as the portion of the training set size.

---

**Use this:**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import random
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])

for i in range(30):
    # the training size will vary between 0.2 and 0.5 randomly
    random_portion = round(random.uniform(0.2, 0.5) , 3)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(X,y, train_size= random_portion, shuffle=True)
```

You can modify the code accordingly.

---

### EDIT 1

**You can do the same using only `numpy` as you wish.**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])

for i in range(30):
    random_portion = round(np.random.rand(),3)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(X,y, train_size= random_portion, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @seralouk. My problem is that I can't import `random` nor `ShuffleSplit`. Just `numpy` and `Train_test_split`.

Comment: is this a task or assignment ? why can't you import random ?

Comment: see my EDIT 1 in my answer

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is an assignment. I cannot import `ShuffleSplit` either.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What do the 1st and 2nd 3 do in the random_portion?

Comment: if I want to have the `same training` every time, but with `random` data chosen from `X`, I should just set the `Shuffle` to `True`, that would be enough, right?

Comment: we only need 1 round command. the 3 means rounding using 3 decimal positions. For your second question, what does the "same training" mean?

Comment: I mean the training should be  50% of data for each round. So in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd round we have 50% of training but in these rounds the data should be chosen differently from the previous round.

Comment: This is totally different than the initial question. If you want to have the same portion of training data across all iterations then specify `train_size= 0.5` and `shuffle=True`. This way, for every iteration you will have 50% as training data and the samples will be shuffled randomly.